# Axios return img Src with Vue JS

Tags: image, vue.js, axios, return, src

Hi all i have this issue i had to return of axios, that I am not positioning in the right place i show my basic code:

```
pictures(city) {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://pixabay.com/api/?key=***********&q=${city}&image_type=photo&pretty=true`
        )
        .then((resp) => {
          if(resp.data.hits.length)
          // console.log(resp.data.hits[0].largeImageURL)
          return resp.data.hits[0].largeImageURL
          else
          // console.log('ELSE')
          return 'https://cdn2.civitatis.com/reino-unido/londres/guia/aeropuerto-gatwick.jpg'
        });
    },
```

And what i want to do, is call this method in my HTML like that

```
<img :src="pictures(item.city)" />
```

And i wait the return that would be a link from the api, but i must be wrong somewhere.
Sorry if it's basic, and if i forgot to do something basic.

Thank you very much for the time taken to my question

Comment: Does the City you're testing with happen to have a space in it?

Comment: No there is no space it comes from algolia api and with console.log i get link url but with return i have no return in fact

Comment: Do you see a response when you console log the largeImageURL? If so, when you inspect the page do you see that URL in the `img` tag of the html generated?

Comment: Yes I've got a link when I console but when I inspect the page html I've nothing or I've a promise when I return axios

Comment: pictures(city) returns undefined, while it should return a string, and it cannot because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call . Making a request and showing a result should be different operations.

Comment: using async/await should probably do the trick for this one